# Erro com servidor Java EE em servidor JBoss

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee, jboss

Olá.

Fiz um projeto no NetBeans em um computar e nele funciona normal, mas quando tento executar o mesmo projeto em outro computador retorna esse erro:

```
Implantando C:\Projetos\confeccao\dist\confeccao.war
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU\": Failed to start service"}}}}
C:\Projetos\confeccao\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1102: O módulo não foi implantado.
Verifique o log do servidor para ver mais detalhes.
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 9 segundos)
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Arquivo **persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ConfeccaoPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!--<jta-data-source>jboss/datasources/ntiProdDS</jta-data-source>-->
    <jta-data-source>java:/ntiDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/ntiDS" pool-name="ntiDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/banco</connection-url>
                <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>usuario</user-name>
                    <password>senha</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Mais detalhes do erro:

```
...
16:44:32,890 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 8.3)
16:44:32,891 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010402: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.postgresql.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.confeccao_warorg_postgresql_Driver_8_3 is already registered
16:44:32,893 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: confeccao.war
16:44:32,914 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU'
16:44:32,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ConfeccaoPU
    ...]
16:44:33,161 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
16:44:33,172 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
16:44:33,179 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
16:44:33,182 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
16:44:33,184 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:44:33,636 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ConfeccaoPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator.render(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.sql.Template.renderOrderByStringTemplate(Template.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.<init>(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.<init>(OneToManyPersister.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:226)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token
    at antlr.CharScanner.makeToken(CharScanner.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByLexer.mIDENT(GeneratedOrderByLexer.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByLexer.nextToken(GeneratedOrderByLexer.java:138)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80)
    at antlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.expression(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.sortKey(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.sortSpecification(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.orderByFragment(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator.render(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:60)
    ... 22 more

16:44:34,011 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "confeccao.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU\": Failed to start service"}}
16:44:35,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment confeccao.war in 1518ms
16:44:35,524 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU": Failed to start service

16:44:35,526 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"confeccao.war#ConfeccaoPU\": Failed to start service"}}}}
```

Comment: Nessa outra máquina tem o Postegres com a base `banco` rodando na porta `5432`?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Sim. nas duas maquinas tem o PostgreSQL na porta 5432 em redes diferente.